# Set the value in a toggle-field on Sencha-touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying save the value of a toggle-field in sencha and send this value to the server, now I am listening the event but it is not working...

My code is:

```
   onHeaderCompleteDelivery: function (button, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log('change fired');
    if(oldValue == 0 && newValue == 1){
        console.log(oldValue);
        this.getCmp('headerCompleteDelivery').setValue(oldValue);
    }
    else {
        console.log(oldValue);
        this.getCmp('headerCompleteDelivery').setValue(oldValue);
    }
},
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are doing, as Ricardo mentioned:

- It looks like the change event of a togglefield you are listening to
- But it seems not to be the standard event as newValue would be the second argument and oldValue the third
- You name the firing component with button, which could indicate that you are listening to a button, but that button won't have the values for a togglefield

This will get you nowhere

---

If this is indeed the togglefield please rewrite your code, to keep it simple

- I have changed the values you are about to set to 0 and 1 to show what will be set at the time.
- I habe removed the second if clause as it it obvious that it is the opposite value.
- I explained what each value is doing as you have the newValue at the wrong position inside the arguments
- if else does not make sense here. I added a short form

.

```
/**
 * togglefield change event
 *
 * @params {object} togglefield
 * @params {number} newValue    the value after the change
 * @params {number} oldValue    the value before the change
 */
 onToggelNameChange: function (togglefield, newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('Togglefield ' + togglefiled.getName() + ' fired change event');
    console.log('Togglefield is now set to: ' + !(!newValue));
    // what is the scope of "this"? you better be sure
    this.getCmp('headerCompleteDelivery').setValue(newValue);

    // or you can try this approach. But make sure header has a value config.
    var header = Ext.Viewport.down('#headerCompleteDelivery');
    header.setValue(newValue);
},
```

---

You should go with a different approach.

- Use a form
- Put the toggelfield into the form and add a name to the field
- Once the submit button is hit get the values from the form (form.getValues())
- Inside the values you will have the current value for the togglefield

here an example:

View

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',

    config: {

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'name',
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name: 'password'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'togglefield',
                        name: 'isActiveToggle',
                        label: 'Test Toggle Field'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        itemId: 'btnSubmit',
                        text: 'Submit'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Controller

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            submitBtn: '#btnSubmit',
        },
        control: {
            submitBtn: { tap: 'onSubmitBtnTap'},
        }
    },

    onSubmitBtnTap: function (btn) {
        var form = btn.up('.form'),
            values = form.getValues();

        // here you will get an Object with
        {
            name: 'Value of name field',
            password: 'Value of password field',
            isActiveToggle: true // <== this is the value you want to send
        }

        this.sendDataToServer(values.isActiveToggle); // your Ajax call with toggleValue
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, maybe It´s a little strange, I am newbie on sencha touch, and my need is "register" the togglefield new value and send this value  to the back-end.  Both cases It´s not working for me, the first one  send "undefined" and the second one, a ambiguous message "<error>"  What is the best way??   Thanks Proto Bassi

Comment: I don´t know that I am doing wrong.. but I cannot get an object (for example) and with getValues() I have an error...  :-(

Comment: can you add console.dir(form) and console.dir(values) and post what you get.

Comment: Message is : 'Cannot read property 'getValues' of undefined'   and my code :                                                       `var field = toggle.up('headerCompleteDelivery'),
            values = field.getValues();
        console.dir(field);
        this.getCmp('headerCompleteDelivery').setValue(values);
        console.dir(values);`

Comment: so field is a form? As you can see field is not defined. Toggle seems not to be inside headerCompeleteDelivery.

Comment: headerCompleteDelivery is an itemId, maybe this is the problem??

Comment: itemId can be found with up and down using #itemId

Comment: if toggle is a valid component of ST and is located inside headerCompleteDelivery it's : toggle.up('#headerCompleteDelivery')

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but looking at the code, both your if and else branches are executing exactly the same code, which may be the problem.

Also, it appears that the oldValue and newValue arguments are inverted in the change event: the newValue argument comes before the oldValue argument (see http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Toggle-event-change).